# code inside if not working even when the condition is satisfied

Tags: java, android

I'm new to Android App Development. I am developing an app in which i have a receiver class. I'm tired of an if statement. The code inside it doesn't execute even when the condition is satisfied. Following is my code:

MyReceiver.java

```
package eg.app7;

import android.app.admin.DevicePolicyManager;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
public static boolean screenOff;
DevicePolicyManager dpm;

SharedPrefs sharedPrefs;



public MyReceiver() {
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    //Toast.makeText(context,"Changed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    System.out.println("onReceive ");
    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
        screenOff = true;
    } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
        screenOff = false;
    }


    // The below if statement is my problem
    if(sharedPrefs.getBoolValue(context,"hhmmkey")) {
        Intent i = new Intent(context, TimePinService.class);
        context.startService(i);
    }



  }
}
```

Please guide me where I'm wrong

Comment: Excuse me, you're getting some error message? And if you change  your last commit to **context.startActivity(i);** ? Oh, I seen now, it's a service...

Comment: No, I'm not getting any error message. And that is supposed to be context.startService(i);

Comment: Are your shure the condition is satisfied? Put a toast toast there to check.

Comment: I don't see where `sharedPrefs` is initiated. Is it initiated?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you added `ACTION_SCREEN_OFF` and `ACTION_SCREEN_ON` to the IntentFilter?

```
public void registerMyReceiver() {
    MyReceiver myReceiver = new MyReceiver();
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();

    intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
    intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);

    registerReceiver(myReceiver, intentFilter);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your suggestions guys. But I found a good fix. I've put the if block inside a service class and then started that service by the receiver class. Works well!